# Оптимизация строчки

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Имеется строчка:

```
gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = L_Pan;
```

Мне не нравится часть с повторением `GetChild()`. Можно ли это оптимизировать?

Скриншот из Unity для понимания ситуации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Намного лучше будет сделать в вашем скрипте сериализуемое поле (объявив его с модификатором доступа public, либо с использованием атрибута [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)), тогда в инспекторе объекта на котором будет ваш скрипт появится поле, в которе вы сможете установить нужный объект (который вы ищете вашей исходной строкой кода ) и производить необходимые над ним действия.

Так же такое решение будет более правильным, потому что в вашем коде вы жестко полагаетесь на иерархию объектов на сцене (или в префабе) и если вы что-то поменяете в иерархии, то вам придется вносить изменения в коде, тогда как создав сериализуемое поле, в случае изменения объекта вы сможете просто перетащить другой объект в редакторе unity без изменения и перекомпиляции скриптов.

Код будет намного компактней и оптимальнее, так как методы `GetComponent` и `GetChild` далеко не самые оптимальные.

Пример кода:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // создаст в инспекторе поле типа Image с названием MyImage
    [SerializeField] private Image _myImage;
    // и далее в нужном вам методе 
    _myImage.sprite = L_Pan;

}
```

Comment: А почему просто не сделать переменную `public Image _myImage;`?  Вы сможете как в редакторе так  и в коде спокойно назначать значение для работы. Зачем все эти сложности с сериализуемым полем, переприсваиванием и т.п.

Comment: @KingPeas чтобы не делать поле _myImage доступным из вне класса и запретить возможность изменения значения из другого класаа, то есть инкапсулировать логику.

Comment: мне кажется это перебор) изначально вопрос был о том как получить доступ к спрайту лучшим образом. Самый удобный и для работы и настройки именно через public поле. Утопите новичка в тонкостях которые ему пока особо не нужны.